# Nested array formation with string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a string as "a.b.c.d:50" so i want to form an array with the above string as `t[a][b][c][d]=50`. so i have tried to split the code and form but this length of n values will generate dynamically. please let me know how we can achieve this.for fixed arrays i tried as below but not able to make this as for n number of arrays.

```
var str1="a.b.c.d:50"; 
var str=str1.split(":");
var dump=str[0].split(".");
t[dump[0]][dump[1]][dump[2]][dump[3]]=dump[4]
```

then result will be `t[a][b][c][d]=50`

Comment: You also need to split dump[3] with `.split(':')` because dump[4] will never be made.

Comment: @PeterBode: i have added that but my main challenge is to form the array

Comment: What is `t[a][b][c][d]` supposed to mean? you can't declare an array as `t["a"]`? This make no sense at all. Are you trying to create an object? what is the structure of this object?

Comment: @Liam : i want to convert that into object. my requirement is i have to read a string like a.b.c.d:50 and the object structure is a.b.c.d and value is 50. i need json object from above string

Comment: `a.b.c.d` is not a valid object structure...

Comment: {"subscriber.userTier.segment": "Red"}   this is my sting i want  to convert this as json object

Comment: As JSON `{"subscriber.userTier.segment": "Red"}` is an object with **one property** `subscriber.userTier.segment`  containing the value `"Red"`. Is this what you want? It seems to be that your JSON is wrong. You JSON should be `{"subscriber":{"userTier":{"segment":"Red"}}}`, that would give you a valid nested JSON object that you could then just call `JSON.Parse()` on. this higlights the pitfalls of using made up data in a question, always try and use the valid data if this is not too complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the JSON string, parse it and iterate all key/value pairs for a nested structure by saving the last key and crate new objects if not exist and assign the vlaue with the last property.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();
    path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
}

var json = '{"subscriber.userTier.segment": "Red"}',
    object = {};

Object
    .entries(JSON.parse(json))
    .forEach(([keys, value]) => setValue(object, keys.split('.'), value));
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use ES6? This is something I just wrote quickly

```
var t = {a:{b:{c:{d:0}}}};
var str = "a.b.c.d:50"

var [chain, value] = str.split(':')
var parts = chain.split('.');
parts.slice(0, -1).reduce((c, v) => c[v], t)[parts[parts.length - 1]] = value;

console.log(t.a.b.c.d); // logs "50"
```

It works, however there is no error handling. If `t['a']['b']` is undefined for example then you will get an uncaught TypeError, also if the string is in the incorrect format etc, it won't work.

At it's heart it uses `reduce` on the array `['a', 'b', 'c']`. We pass `t` as the initial value for the reducer and then for each item in the array it does `currentValue = currentValue[nextPart]`. This will get you the object `c`, we then look at the last value in the `parts` array and set that property `currentValue[lastPart] = value`

That's a brief overview, hopefully you understand the rest of what's going on. If not feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Dirty way of converting a string to a JSON object, if the string is constructed as a valid object.

```js
var str = "a.b.c.d:50";

str = str.replace(/([a-z]){1}/gi, "\"$1\"");

str.split(".").forEach(function (value) {
  str = str.replace(/\.(.*?)$/, ":{$1}");
});

var ar = JSON.parse("{"+str+"}");

console.log(ar);
```